# popup box should not close if user having error in their signup form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This php coding is showing the error message correctly. But, my problem is that popup box does not hold on if the registration form having error. For example, if you click a link one popup box will open. In that popup box i've included a registration form. In this registration form all fields are mandatory. So, user should fill all the fields. if he didn't fill atleast one textfixed php shows the error message.

I got the error message correctly. But, when i submit a form that whole page is refreshing. so, popup box was closed. My question is -> if user having error in registration form that popup box should not close. How to do that?

**PHP**

```
<?php
$errname = "";
$errmobile = "";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$mobile = trim($_POST["mobile"]);

if($_POST["form"] == "values")
{
    if(empty($name))
    {
        $errname = '<span>error</span>';
    }
    if(empty($mobile))
    {
        $errmobile = '<span>error</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>register <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>

<div id="light" class="white_content">
  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="form" value="values" />
      name : <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php $_POST["name"]; ?>" /> <?php if(isset($errname)) echo $errname; ?> <br />
      mobile : <input name="mobile" type="text" value="<?php $_POST["mobile"]; ?>" /> <?php if(isset($errmobile)) echo $errmobile; ?> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with AJAX by this way,

**validation.php**

```
<?php
     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $mobile = $_POST["mobile"];

    if($name == "")
    {
        echo 'error_n';
    }
    if($mobile == "")
    {
        echo 'error_m';
    }
?>
```

**Your HTML**

```
<p>register <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>

<div id="light" class="white_content">
  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
   <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="form" value="values" />
      name : <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />  <br />
      mobile : <input name="mobile" id="mobile" type="text" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

**ajax.js**

Include this JS file in your **HTML**

```
$(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'validation.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {

              if(msg=='error_n')
              {
                  $("#name").val('Name required');                    
              }
              if(msg=='error_m')
              {
                   $("#mobile").val('Mobile required');
              }
            }
          });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
```

Comment: yes its working. popup box doesn't close now. but it does not show the error text?

Comment: and also change `<input name="mobile" id="mobile">` Try to alert(msg); after success

Comment: now it shows the error message. but if i didn't enter both fields it doesn't show the error message.

Comment: Thanks. i will try to clear those remaining errors. i'm new to ajax concept. so, its difficult to understand the ajax coding. i don't know the purpose of these codes `serialize()`, `e.preventDefault();`. provide me some useful link to learn basic ajax coding..

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)   [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to validate the form with javascript before sending to the server. Then you can `return false` if there is an error. in your input add:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onSubmit = "return validate();">
```

then javascript function:

```
 function validate(){

    if(valid == false){
       return false;
       alert('error');
  }
}
```

Comment: here, i'm trying to do server side validation. i don't want to do client side validation here..

Comment: then the page will always reload, unless you make an AJAX call

Comment: how can i do without page refresh?

Comment: if you make an AJAX call you can run the php asynchronously and then return some message back to say if the information is valid or not. I would look into it. I do all my server-side stuff with AJAX